# Invalid block tag: 'get_map_layout', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'

Tags: django, django-templates, django-autocomplete-light

I'm facing a well known `TemplateSyntaxError`. It's a widget made using `django-autocomplete-light`. This is the part of the `if` statement that's rising TemplateSyntaxError`

```
<div id="abstract_map" class="tasky_wall_style careers">
    <h1>
        What our interns saying
    </h1>
    <div class="blue_links global_map">
        <div class="review_container">
            {% if selected_layout %}
            {% get_map_layout layout=selected_layout %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the error:

`Invalid block tag: 'get_map_layout', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'`

I have tried to `{% load get_map_layout %}` in template but other error is risen `'get_map_layout' is not a valid tag library:...`.

Can someone help me understand what is going on so I can solve this.

Comment: Where does the `get_map_layout` template tag come from? Is it included in the top of your template file?

Comment: well that is the problem, when I include it I trigger the other `not valid tag library` error

Comment: Have you included the app that defines that tag in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yes, It's included in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: @PetarP sorry, it says that right there in the question. seems to be time for me to call it a day... :) what's the app that provides `get_map_layout`? I've searched on Google (and the autocomplete light docs) and haven't found a mention. If it is something custom, there may also be an issue with the code of the template tag itself.

Comment: Yes it's a custom widget, here check it out I have pushed it to https://github.com/Copser/reviews/tree/master/reviews

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the last comment I think you are just loading it by the wrong name. Instead of `{% load get_map_layout %}` try **`{% load reviews %}`** on top of your template.

Django resolves custom template tags through the name of the Python module they are defined in (`reviews/templatetags/reviews.py` in that case), so `{% load reviews %}`  should make all template tags defined in `reviews.py` available in your template.